# randomly create a portfolio of a given size

Tags: algorithm, finance

There are 100 different stocks in total to choose from. Each stock has a price, p_i, I want to create random portfolios for simulation purposes. The total value of the portfolio needs to be $1,000,000 (give or take $100) and the number of different shares in the portfolio can be random too (for example the portfolio could be long in 20 stocks). I'm struggling to create "a good" algorithm to do this.

It's not really a knapsack problem because nothing needs to be optimized. It is kind of like a random sample but not quite. So I'm wondering what algorithm I could use to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Choose `N` number of stocks from the total universe of stocks
- Generate `N` random floats, `X_1`, ..., `X_N`, between 0 and 1
- Let T = the sum of the numbers = `X_1 + ... + X_N`. If `T` equals 0, repeat step 1.
- Normalize the numbers: `X_1 = X_1 / T`, ... `X_N = X_N / T`. Notice *the sum `X_1 + ... + X_N` now equals 1*.
- Let `W` = the value of the total portfolio (e.g. `W = 1000000`)
- Invest `X_i * W` dollars in the `i`th stock
- The number of shares bought of the `i`th stock is therefore `S_i = X_i * W / p_i`

---

In Python,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format

N = 100
W = 10**6
portfolio_size = np.random.randint(1, N+1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.uniform(1, 100, size=(N,))})
df = df.iloc[np.random.choice(N, portfolio_size, replace=False)]
while True:
    df['value'] = np.random.random(portfolio_size)
    T = df['value'].sum()
    if T != 0: break
df['value'] *= W/T
df['shares'] = df['value']/df['price']
df.index.name='stock num'
print(df)
print('Total value of portfolio: {}'.format(df['value'].sum()))
```

yields something like

```
           price     value  shares
stock num                         
0          34.52  65296.14 1891.72
24          6.82  13008.12 1906.35
83         15.56 100550.05 6463.14
12         60.35  30366.58  503.17
77         76.75 100814.58 1313.49
36         96.50  85649.01  887.53
51         26.28  96860.06 3685.21
9          43.22  31757.96  734.87
56         67.33  19889.57  295.40
66         79.99  30343.49  379.34
21          1.45   1718.19 1187.56
30         34.48  33604.31  974.65
52         80.15  64579.28  805.71
55         41.02  10226.60  249.29
40          8.49  25755.19 3032.82
20         89.46 102164.38 1142.06
5          45.94  42620.16  927.71
73         96.17   6021.88   62.62
58         60.00  24133.96  402.21
45         40.59 114640.49 2824.31
Total value of portfolio: 1000000.0
```

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstand the algo here - but the resulting portfolio is not really random. Suppose T=3. Then we've invested an equal amount of cash in 3 stocks. This method would exclude portfolios where a different amount of cash is invested in different stocks.

Comment: `T=3` does not mean `X1, X2, ..., X_N` are equal. They could be `X1=1, X2=2, X3=0` for instance. In which case you would invest 1/3 of your wealth, `W`, in stock #1, and 2/3 of your wealth in stock #2, and 0/3 of your wealth in stock #3. I used integer values of `X1, X2, X3` to make the example simple, but in general the `X` values can be floats.

Comment: What do you mean by "Generate N random numbers, X_1, ..., X_N, from 0 to 1 (inclusive)"? I understood the x_i's are binary

Comment: I mean random floats between 0 and 1. (I'll edit to hopefully clarify).

Comment: this algorithm would almost surely choose portfolios with all 100 stocks included since 0 has no mass; P(X_i=0)=0 under a continuous distribution

Comment: Your problem statement does not state how many stocks you wish to select for a portfolio so I assumed you wanted (potentially) a piece of each.

Comment: No as in the example I gave a portfolio with only 20 stocks is perfectly valid.

Comment: You said "20 shares" not "20 stocks"!?

Comment: OK now we're talking. Shares & Stocks are synonymous terms to me. So apologies for the confusion. But by choosing portfolio_size as random integer on [1,100] in your solution does the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems fairly trivial - I will give a java example, but of course you can use any language:

```
int MAX_PORTFOLIO = 1000000;     //the cap on your portfolio value
Stock[] stocks = new Stock[100]; //fill this with your stocks

Portfolio p = new Portfolio();   //make a new portfolio object
while(p.getValue() < MAX_PORTFOLIO ) {
 //randomly pick a stock to buy
 int stockIndex = rand.nextInt(stocks.length());

 //find out the max # of this stock that can be bought without exceeding max portfolio value
 int remainingSpaceInPortfolo = MAX_PORTFOLIO - p.getValue();
 int stocksToFillRemaining = Math.floorDiv(remainingSpaceInPortfolio, stocks[stockIndex].getPrice());

 //randomly choose a number of stock to buy
 int numStockToBuy = rand.nextInt(stocksToFillRemaining) + 1;
 p.buy(stocks[stockIndex], numStockToBuy);
}
```

Note this assumes you have some object `Portfolio` which has a `getValue()` and a `buy(Stock toBuy, int numToBuy)` method and some object `Stock` which has a `getPrice()` method. Both should be very easy to implement, and I won't detail them here as your question was about the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks - this is something similar to what I concocted. I wasn't happy with the performance (maybe I'm being unnecessarily scrutinous here). Perhaps I should have made this clearer in the question.

Comment: @mark Hm... I'm not sure how you can get better performance given that you want the values to be random. I mean you need a loop that goes until the portfolio is full. One thing you could do is make sure the random generation buys at least x of a stock - that would reduce the loop iterations, but not the worst case big O time complexity.

Comment: Yes you're probably right. I'm using python so was looking for like a vectorized solution. But as you might have seen from the comments on the other solutions - this is tricky (well at least for me). To truely come up with a random portfolio.